# Date conversation taking too much memory

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am executing following code for date localization. But it's taking too much memory (approx ~2 gb).

```
 var options = {  
        year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric',
        hour: 'numeric', minute : 'numeric', 
        second: 'numeric' ,timeZone : 'Asia/Calcutta', 
        timeZoneName: 'short',hour12 : false};
 var _ts;

// length approx 80k
var _array = [1486901778700, 1486901778700, ....., 1386901778700.0 ] 
var final_string = ''

for(var key in _array) {
  //======>>this conversation taking too much memory (around ~2gb) <<======
  _ts_string = new Date(_debug_data.timestamp).toLocaleString('en-US', options)
  final_string += _ts_string
}
```

So question is here:-
- Why is it taking too much memory ??
- Any alternate of this date conversation  or any optimization way??
- If it's taking too much memory then why isn't releasing memory after code execution?? (Even I have manually called "gc()" still memory did not release.)
- I have try to control memory limit (heap size) by command line (--max-old-space) but it's fail.
- I have try with upstart limit option (provide hard and soft limit) to control in-memory limit but didn't work.

I am using node 0.12.8 version.

Any help is appreciable. :)

Comment: What do the contents of your loop have to do with `key` or `_array`? Also, `for..in` is for _Object_ iteration, if you know you want to iterate over an _Array_ use a normal [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for). `_ts_string` looks like it's becoming a global?

Comment: is it required to create new Date object for each iteration?

Comment: @PaulS. I forgot to mention here. It was already defined.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal: any alternate way ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the new inside the loop. You're creating a new Date object for each item. Inside the loop, try:

```
final_string += Date(_debug_data.timestamp).toLocaleString('en-US', options);
```

You are also missing ";" on several lines.

Comment: Let me try and update you with result and whole npm write without ";". It doesn't matter... :)

Comment: -1. Invoking [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) without `new` does something very different. This will not work.

Comment: @Bergi why -1, invoking `Date` as a function returns string and that's what OP is trying to do.

Comment: @Sloan Thrasher I want to hit stone on my head. Why I did not do this thing. It's working perfectly. :) :)

Comment: @ManishTrivedi: We all have plenty of brick marks on our foreheads from beating our heads against the wall ;-). Glad it's working!

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal Exactly that, because it returns a string. The `.toLocaleString` method invoked on that will be [the `Object` one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toLocaleString), not `Date::toLocaleString` (what the OP wanted). Either you should drop the method or you should add the `new`.

Comment: @Bergi try these in order - `var d = Date.now()` then `var s = Date(d).toLocaleString()` and then print value of `s`. These represent what OP is trying to do and is absolutely fine.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal You should do only `var s = Date(d);`, `toLocaleString` just returns the input. The problem with this approach is that it doesn't consider the arguments `'en-US', options` but looks as if it did.

Comment: @Bergi you are absolutely right with 'Date' and 'new Date' concept But I skip the date conversion.  Actually I have UTC time and I am converting it into UTC+5.30 with human reading string. But due to too much memory consuming I am serving data with UTC.  Still I have lots of question like why v8 is not releasing memory after consuming it ?? Even I have restrict heap size still It's hungry for memory.

Answer (score 0):

Since javascript strings are unmutable maybe creating an array of strings first then joining them  at the end would be faster/lighter.

```
var strings = [];
for(var key in _array) {
  strings.push(new Date(_debug_data.timestamp).toLocaleString('en-US', options));
}

var final_string = strings.join();
console.log(strings.length);
```

But anyways, 80k date object will take some resources & time obviously.